# How to delete 30 days old logs in Elastic search through elastic search ILM

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-8

Im having elastic search account ,deployed via aws marketplace.
I have few deployments in my elastic search account , some elastic search deployments storage is full , i can't find way to delete 30 days old logs for that particular deployment.
Can anyone guide me through correct way to delete old logs in my case.
elastic search version = v8.5.3

Comment: You need to set up Index Lifecycle Management policies. Read up a little on that and let us know if you need more help: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-lifecycle-management.html

Comment: Thanks for you response @Val . will creating single ILM sufficient for all my elastic search deployments.
Regarding index , i followed this https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/set-up-lifecycle-policy.html
Since im new to this how can i relate it my case ,  what index pattern i need to give here. how can i map it for my case.

Comment: One deployment = one cluster, so a lifecycle policy created for one cluster will not be available to the others, you'll need to create one or more ILM per deployment/cluster. You need to update your question with a bit more details, such as which indexes you want to manage using a lifecycle, etc

Comment: Below are my indices:
.ds-logs-enterprise_search.audit-default-2023.09.22-000001, .ds-metrics-apm.service_transaction.1m-default-2023.09.22-000001, .ds-logs-enterprise_search.api-default-2023.09.22-000001, .ds-logs-apm.error-default-2023.09.22-000001, .ds-metrics-apm.service_summary.1m-default-2023.09.22-000001, .ds-metrics-apm.internal-default-2023.09.22-000001, .ds-metrics-apm.service_destination.1m-default-2023.09.22-000001, .ds-metrics-apm.transaction.1m-default-2023.09.22-000001, .ds-traces-apm-default-2023.09.22-000001 How can i create create ILM based on my indices,

Comment: my indices are like above , in my case , i followed this https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.5/set-up-lifecycle-policy.html
how can i relate my index , what value do i need to give for index pattern.
step 1 : i created a policy as it is from above link
step 2 : created index , my index pattern [timeseries-*]
How can i proceed further in mycase

Comment: Most of the indexes you listed are APM and enterprise search indexes which should already be managed by an ILM policy. You can maybe modify those existing policies and shorten the retention duration, usually 30 days, but you can make it shorter

Comment: Thanks for your response @Val , i don't want to modify existing confgs, 
instead i need to create new ILM policy, which should take care of logs deletion.
How can i proceed it from here.

Comment: Those indices you mention are automatically created by ES and Elastic Agent, as such they get assigned default ILM policies. So you'll need to either modify those existing policies OR assign a new one to the indexes. Some modifications are required as you cannot assign several ILM policies to a given index.

Comment: Ok understood, suppose if i modify existing ILM policy , will it be applicable to all elastic deployments created in our account and also to future elastic search deployments.

Comment: Re-read my second comment in this thread, one deployment = one cluster and ILM policies are cluster-specific